# How can I remove this type of tables name [somepreffix].table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a db of an organization where all the tables look like this:
EMPRE01.table1
EMPRE01.table2 
etc.
[image]

if I type this query: `SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U'` 
I will get this result as table names: table1, table2
But if I try this query: `SELECT * FROM table1` it won't work 
only if I type it like this: `SELECT * FROM EMPRE01.table1`

How can I convert the db to "normal" mode?

Comment: You can specify a default database for your session by `use <db_name>`.  But you would be better off using the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type the query :

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

It will search as `dbo.table1`. As, because `dbo` is a default schema. You need to explicit state the schema name :

So,

```
SELECT * FROM EMPRE01.table1
```

Note : This assumes query is working with same database.

Comment: You confuse dbo and default schema - which is not helpful. The default schema is always used first to find an object when it is not schema qualified. Don't assume dbo is the default schema. And your last statement is equally confusing. You do not need to "change" the default schema - you simply need to qualify the object name with the appropriate schema.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I used this query to change tables to dbo. And it worked perfect. '''SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [' + SysSchemas.Name + '].[' + DbObjects.Name + '];'
FROM sys.Objects DbObjects
INNER JOIN sys.Schemas SysSchemas ON DbObjects.schema_id = SysSchemas.schema_id
WHERE SysSchemas.Name <> 'dbo'
AND (DbObjects.Type IN ('U', 'P', 'V'))'''